# Error PRVF-7536 Installing Oracle ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)

Tags: oracle, windows-10, oracle12c, odac

I'm trying to install the Oracle ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) on my Windows 10 Pro x64 machine but I'm facing a very weird error in the "Perform Prerequisites Checks" step, AFAIK the error is telling me I'm using the wrong package for my machine's architecture, but I'm pretty sure my machine is x64 and the Oracle package is also for x64.

I've tried running the installer as an Administrator also ignoring the sys prerequisites executing this from an elevated cmd `Setup.exe -ignoreSysPrereqs` and also selecting the checkbox to ignore the prereqs in the wizard, but can't get it working.

My Machine Info:
[image]

I downloaded the installer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html), second option:
[image]

The error:
[image]

I'll appreciate your help

**Update 1:** As suggested by @JuanK I checked the ram memory and hard drive space available at the moment of trying to install, It does not seem to be the problem:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the generated log file to see if it reports any other errors - maybe this is a knock-on error form something else but ends up getting reported in the GUI?

Comment: @AlexPoole No, I did not. Could you tell me where can I find the log?

Comment: I believe it's just in the installation directory you chose, as install..log. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @AlexPoole No luck finding the log, there is no log file in the temp folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess You should execute the installer running on windows 8 compatibility mode

File, properties, compatibility

[image]

Anyway I've just tested the full installation without problems, from the steps the installer followed and based on your screenshot I guess you haven't enough free space in your hard disk or even in memory.

This is my success screenshot

[image]

Have you clicked on `Ignore All` checkbox and tried pressing `Next/Install` ?

Comment: Unfortunately It does not work, I tried selecting the compatibility mode an running it as administrator

Comment: Are you sure your OS is running on 64 bit mode?

Comment: Yes I am, I added to the question a printscreen of my machine settings

Comment: Please attach the url you have used to download the installer, I'm going to replicate the environment.

Comment: I updated the question with the disk and memory usage at the time the error arise

Comment: "Have you clicked on Ignore All checkbox and tried pressing Next/Install ?" This is what saved me. Thanks !

Comment: Windows 8 compatibility mode and running install as administrator worked for me.